# Sparse matrix operations on CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, sparse-matrix, cusp-library

I work on converting a large Matlab code to C++ and CUDA. I have problems converting some sparse matrix operations like:

```
1. full_Matrix    *  sparse_Matrix
2. sparse_Matrix  *  full_Matrix
3. sparse_Matrix  *  sparse_Matrix    (SOLVED WITH CUSP)
4. full_Matrix   .*  sparse_Matrix    (elementwise multiplication)
5. sparse_Matrix  *  full_Matrix      (elementwise multiplication)
6. sparse_Matrix .*  sparse_Matrix    (elementwise multiplication)
```

I was able to solve 2 using CUSPARSE and 3 using CUSP, however I wasn't able to use CUSP (or CUSPARSE)  for elementwise matrix multiplication or for problem 1.

I'm interested if there is a CUDA library that implements all the above operations (preferably an open source one).

Comment: @Anycorn While theoretically correct, you are doing 3 transpositions which can be overkill (depends on your arrays size of course).

Comment: you should be able to specify transpose flags, hence only 1 transpose.

Comment: I stand corrected only 2 transpose. If you use Cusparse you can specify the transpose flag only for the left array.